# Linking to a component from the same component doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component, let's say `MyComponent`, accessible through a route like this:

```
 <Route path="/myComponent/:id" exact component={MyComponent} />
```

**Inside** `MyComponent` I have:

```
 <Link to="/myComponent/2">2</Link>
```

That is, MyComponent links to itself. But this link does not work! If I inspect the React component through Chrome's developer tools, then `props.match` has been updated accordingly, but `MyComponent` has not been re-rendered and the constructor has not been recalled so that the state can be updated accordingly.

Minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-bouman-i1b0p?fontsize=14 - if you browse to [this URL](https://i1b0p.csb.app/myComponent/1) then you'll see the ID 1 appear on the rendered screen, but if you click on the 2 link the screen will not rerender even though the URL does update. If you go to [this URL](https://i1b0p.csb.app/myComponent/2) then the ID 2 will appear as expected.

Comment: Are you sure your sandbox reflects your actual problem ? I have tried your sandbox and the component does re-render each time the link is clicked (I just added a console.log in the render method)

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I changed the description to make it a little clearer what the problem is.. are you sure it's rerendering for you when you're on the '/1' url and clicking '2'? (By rerendering I mean showing '2' above the link)

Answer (score 0):

If the component is already mounted, React router reuses the component instance. Hence constructor or `componentDidMount` hooks are not called.

You can fix this by adding a `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { id } = this.props.match.params;
  if(id !== this.state.id) {
    this.setState({
      id
    });
  }
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-golick-vfbpg)

Comment: Is there a way to force remounting? The example in the sandbox is a bit contrived, the parameters passed through the link are somewhat complex - also prone to change, meaning that every change would have to reflect twice in the code. This seems oddly inelegant for React, am I doing something wrong by trying to link from a component to the same component?

Answer (score 0):

AAAH ! It does re-render with no problem. It is just your state.id that is never updated. You should either use your props as-is or keep your state up-to-date:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {
      match: { params }
    } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      // This will only ever happen once !
      id: params.id
    };
  }
  // this will keep your state in sync with your props
  componentDidUpdate (lastProps) {
    if (lastProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.setState({ id: this.props.match.params.id }) 
    }
  }
  render() {
    // uncommenting the following line and deleting the next one will make your whole state useless
    // const { id } = this.props.match.params
    const { id } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{id}</div>
        <Link to="/myComponent/2">2</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```